# Converting a supposed excel file in csv in python

Tags: excel, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I am having an issue trying to use a code for converting a file into csv.
I am using the code below as a start

```
directory = 'C:\OI Data'

filename = 'OpenInterest08-24-16'

data_xls = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(directory,filename), 'Sheet1',    index_col=None)
    data_xls.to_csv(os.path.join(directory,filename +'.csv'), encoding='utf-8')
```

and I am getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
>       exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
>
> File "C:/Users/Public/Documents/Python Scripts/work.py", line 26, in 
>       data_xls = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(directory,filename), 'Sheet1', index_col=None)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 170, in read_excel
>       io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 227, in **init**
>       self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xlrd__init__.py", line 441, in open_workbook
>       ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 91, in open_workbook_xls
>       biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1230, in getbof
>       bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])
>
> File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1224, in bof_error
>       raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
>   xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '\n\n\n\n\n   '

I am struggling to figure out the file format I am using
https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/icefuturesus/PreliminaryOpenInterest.shtml?futuresExcel=&tradeDate=8%2F24%2F16

opening the file myself I get the following
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHEct.png)

I am still a beginner at python and some help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is your file an `xls` or `xlsx` file? pandas will choose the appropriate parser depending on the extension and there doesn't appear to be one...

Comment: This is problematic: `data_xls.to_csv(os.path.join(directory,filename,'.csv'), encoding='utf-8')`...

Comment: Try instead: `data_xls.to_csv(os.path.join(directory,filename+'.csv'), encoding='utf-8')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by fixing this part:

```
data_xls.to_csv(os.path.join(directory,filename,'.csv'), encoding='utf-8')
```

What happens when you do that is:

```
'C:\OI Data\\OpenInterest08-24-16\\.csv'
```

Which is not what you want. Instead do:

```
os.path.join(directory,filename+'.csv')
```

Which will give you:

```
'C:\OI Data\\OpenInterest08-24-16.csv'
```

Also, this is not a problem here, but in general be careful with this because a single backslash and a character can indicate an escape sequence, e.g. `\n` is a newline:

```
directory = 'C:\OI Data'
```

Instead escape the backslash like so:

```
directory = 'C:\\OI Data'
```